# What does this line of code in UI sortable mean?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the UI jquery sortable plugin and have found some code that I am going to use but there is one part I don't understand. It is "onChange: "function(serialized) { widgets_positions(); }"

onChange doesn't appear in the documentation. Widgets_positions is a function that I understand about which tracks the positions of the objects being moved around. But I need to understand the 'onChange: function(serialized)' part.

```
                $('#col').Sortable(
                    {
                        accept: 'widget',
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        helperclass: 'helper',
                        onChange: function(serialized) { widgets_positions(); },
                        handle: '.widget_title_bar'
                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that is supposed to be change:

```
    $( ".selector" ).sortable({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

I have used the change event before when the order of the list is changed.  ui gives you access to the dom element changed.

You could put your function call in the change event.

Comment: I see. So it is a mistake. And what does function(serialized) do? When the order of the list is changed widgets_positions is ran, but I don't see what 'function(serialized)' achieves?

Comment: @James: Nothing, as the `serialized` parameter is not used within the function. Also your code is either not jQuery UI, or it's completely wrong. `.sortable()` should be written all lowercase, `onChange` is `change`, and the `serialized` variable would actually hold an event object. Are you sure it's not a custom widget that the code belongs to?